# Firebase cloud function update is not working everytimg a write happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I programmed a cloud function to check for Write event and process accordingly.

Following is the data I'm writing

```
    [ {
  "fromId" : 2750,
  "fromName" : "TAKETHAN",
  "m" : "DEAR PARENT,\nTHIS IS COMMON MESSAGING SYSTEM",
  "to" : [ {
    "mobileNumber" : "91854xx3x3xx",
    "uuid" : "5b3b32eb67bfe0.55083386"
  } ]
} ]
```

The following is the cloud function code.

```
exports.processMessageQueue = functions.database.ref('/messageQueue/{pushId}')
  .onWrite((change, context)  => {
    var updateMessage = {};
    for (var messageCounter in change.after.val()) {
      var toMobileNumbers = change.after.child(messageCounter).child("to").val();
      var message = change.after.child(messageCounter).child("m").val();
      var messageFromID = change.after.child(messageCounter).child("fromId").val();
      var messageTime = Date.now() * -1;
      var messageFromName = change.after.child(messageCounter).child('fromName').val();


      for (var toCounter in toMobileNumbers) {
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/chatThread/${messageFromID}/${messageTime}`] = message;
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/inbox/${messageFromID}/fromName`] = messageFromName;
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/inbox/${messageFromID}/message`] = message;
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/inbox/${messageFromID}/time`]=messageTime;

        // console.log(`To(${toCounter})`,`${toMobileNumbers[toCounter]}`);
        var OSmessage = {
          app_id: "xxxx",
          contents: {"en": message},
          headings:{"en":messageFromName},
          data:{"uuid":toMobileNumbers[toCounter].uuid},
          filters: [
                        {"field":"tag","key": `M${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}`, "relation": "exists"}
                    ]
        };
        console.log(OSmessage);
        sendNotification(OSmessage);

      }
      // console.log("UM",updateMessage);
    }
    // console.log("UMM",updateMessage);
    //do not fire when it's deleted
if (change.after.exists()) {
    admin.database().ref().update(updateMessage)
    .then(()=>change.after.ref.remove())
    .then(()=>console.log(`M:${messageFromName} - ${message}`)).catch(function(error) {
      alert("Data could not be updated." + error);
    });
}
return "Completed!";
  });
```

The `sendNotification(OSmessage);` function I'm calling in the function is working fine and it works everytime a write event is happened. But the following code doesnot work everytime. It works more than 95% of the time. I'm not even getting a catched error in the log.

```
var sendNotification = function(data) {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic NGY5YTE4ODgtNWI"
  };

  var options = {
    host: "onesignal.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v1/notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
  };
console.log("OneSignallingx:",data['filters'][0]['key']);
  var https = require('https');
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("OneSignalling Back",JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.end();
};
```

Comment: Because you are not returning promises properly, what do you have in `sendNotification(OSmessage)` can you paste the code?

Comment: Also, you are executing a big chunk of code whenever you update, delete, create and write data, do you want to execute that code in each case?

Comment: @d.mares I've updated the description. Please check.

Comment: I'm only running the update once for each write.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
exports.processMessageQueue = functions.database.ref('/messageQueue/{pushId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
  if (change.after.exists()) {
    const promises=[];
    var updateMessage = {};
    for (var messageCounter in change.after.val()) {
      var toMobileNumbers = change.after.child(messageCounter).child("to").val();
      var message = change.after.child(messageCounter).child("m").val();
      var messageFromID = change.after.child(messageCounter).child("fromId").val();
      var messageTime = Date.now() * -1;
      var messageFromName = change.after.child(messageCounter).child('fromName').val();
      for (var toCounter in toMobileNumbers) {
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/chatThread/${messageFromID}/${messageTime}`] = message;
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/inbox/${messageFromID}/fromName`] = messageFromName;
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/inbox/${messageFromID}/message`] = message;
        updateMessage[`/messaging/${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}/inbox/${messageFromID}/time`] = messageTime;
        var OSmessage = {
          app_id: "xxxx",
          contents: { "en": message },
          headings: { "en": messageFromName },
          data: { "uuid": toMobileNumbers[toCounter].uuid },
          filters: [
            { "field": "tag", "key": `M${toMobileNumbers[toCounter].mobileNumber}`, "relation": "exists" }
          ]
        };
        promises.push(sendNotification(OSmessage));
      }
    }
    promises.push(admin.database().ref().update(updateMessage));
    promises.push(change.after.ref.remove());
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
  return null;
});

var sendNotification = function(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization": "Basic NGY5YTE4ODgtNWI"
    };
    var options = {
      host: "onesignal.com",
      port: 443,
      path: "/api/v1/notifications",
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers
    };
    var https = require('https');
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("OneSignalling Back", JSON.parse(data));
      });
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("ERROR:");
      console.log(e);
    });
    req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    req.end();
    req.on('end', function(e) {
      resolve();
    });
  })
};
```

Comment: or you can resolve the promise `on('data'...` after you do whatever you want to do with the data

Comment: Also I changed your code to this `return Promise.all(promises).then(()=>change.after.ref.remove());` . I want the data removed only after the successfull updation. Is it correct ?

Comment: I'm getting a timeout even for a small set of data.

Comment: in your then are you returning a promise? `return change.after.ref.remove()`

Comment: `.then(()=>change.after.ref.remove());` this is enough, right ?

Comment: no, each then should return a value or promise `.then(()=> return change.after.ref.remove());`

Comment: ` return Promise.all(promises).then(()=> return change.after.ref.remove());
                                           ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token return` 
this is what I'm getting when I added return .

Comment: On the other case the code in `sendNotification` function `req.on('end', function(e) {
      console.log("OS_Resolved",data.contents) resolve(); });`  is not console logging.

Comment: try this `return admin.database().ref(``messageQueue/${context.params.pushId}``).remove()`

Comment: I think it was a problem with `resolve()` in `sendNotification`. When I put `resolve()` in `var req = https.request(options, function(res) {res.on('data', function(data) {resolve()});});` it's working. I'm not sure it's the right way.